# PLS-00225 subprogram or cursor '' reference is out of scope when try to read column names

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to return the column names and the value as a pair key/value like this:

column_name     | column_value
dep_id          | 1 
dep_name        | 'Test' 
dep_create_date | '08-25-2021'

```
declare
cursor c_dept is select * from department
begin
  for r_d in c_dept loop
  
    for c in c_dept."COLUMNS" loop
      dbms_output.put_line('Column name '|| c.name);
      dbms_output.put_line('Column value '|| c.value);
    end loop;
    
  end loop;
end;
```

When I execute this block, I got the following error message:

Error report -
ORA-06550: line 6, column 22:
PLS-00225: subprogram or cursor 'C_DEPT' reference is out of scope
ORA-06550: line 6, column 5:

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you can remove the part `."COLUMNS"` Then replace `c.name` with `c.dep_name`, and `c.value` with `c.dep_id`

Comment: You're printing the result (and only if the client handles the dbms_output buffer), not returning anything. And not in anything like the format you showed. What will consume the output - maybe you wanted to generate JSON instead, as you refer to key/value; or XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `DBMS_SQL` package:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_cursor PLS_INTEGER;
  v_cnt    PLS_INTEGER;
  v_desc   dbms_sql.desc_tab;
  i        PLS_INTEGER;
  v_ignore PLS_INTEGER;
  v_value  VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  v_cursor := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
  dbms_sql.parse(
    v_cursor,
    'select 1 as dep_id, ''Test'' as dep_name from dual',
    dbms_sql.native
  );
  dbms_sql.describe_columns(v_cursor, v_cnt, v_desc);

  i := v_desc.FIRST; 
  LOOP
    EXIT WHEN i IS NULL;
    dbms_sql.define_column(v_cursor, i, v_value, 4000);
    i := v_desc.NEXT(i);
  END LOOP;

  v_ignore := dbms_sql.execute(v_cursor);
  LOOP
    EXIT WHEN dbms_sql.fetch_rows(v_cursor) <= 0;
    i := v_desc.FIRST; 
    LOOP
      EXIT WHEN i IS NULL;
      dbms_sql.column_value(v_cursor, i, v_value);
      dbms_output.put_line('Column_name: ' || v_desc(i).COL_NAME);
      dbms_output.put_line('Column_value: ' || v_value);
      i := v_desc.NEXT(i);
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
  dbms_sql.close_cursor(v_cursor);
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> Column_name: DEP_ID
> Column_value: 1
> Column_name: DEP_NAME
> Column_value: Test
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=962468a788cdb14e9b89cbb9b477a6aa)*